# Elements on my html page move when i resized my browser

Tags: html, css

All of my elements move when i resized my browser and i don't understand why.

But i want them to stay at their own position, also when i resized my browser, so, how can i do this in css ?

Thanks you !

```css
body {
    background-color: #c3ced4;
}

.select_dev {
    width: 380px;
    height: 850px;
    background-color: #142431;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.excel_preview {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 40px;
    min-width: 1450px;
    min-height: 720px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Preview</title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="select_dev">
        <div class="dev">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-page">
        <div class="top-name">D-FRAGMENT</div>
        <div class="top-choice"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="excel_preview">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check by providing the width in px?

Comment: ?? Sorry i didn't understood, the larger is already in the css file..

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use a height or width with %, you make them responsive to changes on the window size, as they adjust to the size of the container.

If you want them to be independent of the window size, you should give them a fixed size in pxs.

Then, if you do want to change the size for devices such as mobile, the ideal solution would be to implement mediaqueries:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I forgot to change the value on my css, but all of my value are already in px, but it change the place of the element when i resize my browser...

Comment: I've placed your reviewed code on a codepen and it looks fine. The elements don't change place...